# PHP Order By Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am having hard time to solve this puzzle. I have a website which is showing some products. I am trying to show the product by ASC order but it is not working properly.

Here is my current query and output:

```
$sql=executeQuery("select * from ".PREFIX."prod_info where prodId='".$pId."' order by ProductName+0) ASC");


AM 65
AM 67
AM 69
AM 104 (Chuck) 
AM 105 (Sin) 
AM 73
AM 76
AC 20
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please edit your question to show an example of the output you're expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have:

```
order by ProductName
```

Instead of:

```
order by ProductName+0
```

The latter converts `ProductName` to an integer.  If it starts with a letter, then it will be treated as `0`.  What is probably happening is that all are starting with letters, all get ordered by the value `0` -- and nothing interesting is happening.

EDIT:

You appear to want to order the `ProductName` alphabetically by the first two digits and then numerically by the rest.  You can do this as:

```
order by left(ProductName, 2),
         char_length(ProductName),
         ProductName
```

If you really have extraneous words at the end, after the number, then it gets harder.  The following may work better:

```
order by left(ProductName, 2),
         substr(ProductName, 3) + 0,
         ProductName
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did tried but it is not working either. The output is  AM 139, AM 140, AM 141, AM 142, AM 16, AM 2

Comment: Okay. Great! 2nd option solved my issue. Thanks again for your help.